# How use combined class style as inline Style in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want add cssTransition styles using inline style in react. But some styles couldn't add.

Example:

```
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

I tried with

```
 'exampleEnter-exampleEnterActive': {
   opacity: 1,
   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in
 }
```

But it not work, anybody can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium) to make that work.